# Can a woman become pregnant through splash pregnancy?

Tags: physiology, pregnancy, human-reproduction

I have read that there is something called "splash pregnancy" which is when you get pregnant without having penetration. So far I have only found [anecdotal stories](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=25269) about it, but is there any documented case? If so, what are the chances?

Comment: surely you don't propose a test...

Comment: Can we remove refences to “virgin”? It doesn’t seem relevant and I dislike it as a qualifier since definitions differ (a lot!). For instance, your question seems to assume that it means “no vaginal penetration” but there are other, just as valid, definitions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlikely but possible according to http://www.americanpregnancy.org/preventingpregnancy/pregnancyfaqmyths.html

> Can sperm travel through clothing or material? If the clothing was completely saturated with semen and was in direct contact with a woman’s vagina, there is a very slight chance the sperm could enter the vagina, but this is highly unlikely. No conclusive studies have been found to give a definite answer on this possibility.

While I can't find any cited cases, it seems that it's physiologically possible with close contact - ejaculation directly on or near the vaginal area, or ejaculation spread onto the vaginal area by clothing. Sperm loses potency quickly outside the body.

Comment: How exactly does one conduct such a study? The only feasible thing i can think of is animal studies.

Comment: Possible, but the chances would be millions less than normal insemination

Comment: @Charlie Flowers: after-the-fact reports?